# element.uploadFile does not work with some image upload components

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to upload an image in https://my.gumtree.com/postad but it doesn't' work and doesn't give any errors either.

This is how image component looks like.

[image: image text]

This is the html source for this component:

```html
<div id="html5_1e23hbscjgte1ni1goba4orb2_container" class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 8px; width: 130px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;"><input id="html5_1e23hbscjgte1ni1goba4orb2" type="file" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" multiple="" accept="image/jpeg,.jpg,.jpeg,image/png,.png"> </div>
```

This is the code i'm using. I tried both

```
const fileInput = await page.$('input[type=file]');
await fileInput.uploadFile('./img1.jpeg');
```

and

```
const inputUploadHandle = await page.$('input[type=file]');
inputUploadHandle.uploadFile(...['img1.jpeg']);
```

But doesn't work.
I also tried using full paths but no luck.

Can someone please point out what is the issue here?

Comment: Do you have only one `input[type=file]`?

Comment: Yes it selects the element correctly. I did confirm that

Comment: the path of the image is correct?

Comment: the paths of the image is different in your question

Comment: Yes i tried both variations mentioned above and also adding full path. but nothing happens and doesn't get any errors

Comment: Anyone has any idea why it does not work